# jQuery / jQuery mobile - refresh page formatting after .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery, jQuery mobile, js, hotml & css.

I have a filterable list on the index page

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-icon="false" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search all cards..." data-inset="true" id="menutest">
```

and then use .append in the js to bring in some extra LI's from an external html file unto the UL.

```
$.get('menus/menutest.html',function(data) {
   $('#menutest').append('<li>' + data + '</li>');
})
```

Which works great, except - the incoming LI's are stripped of their usual jquery formatting. And for example, if I put ' data-filter-reveal="true" ' in the UL, everything else is hidden except for the new stuff.

But, when I start typing into the filter box, suddenly everything is formatted correctly. And stays correct even if I clear the filter text.

I can't work out what part of the filter activating corrects the formatting, and therefore how I can force it to happen myself?

Comment: after append: `$("#menutest").listview("refresh");` should work.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the existing LI all had classes assigned to them, but the appended ones didn't. Then when the filter is activated, suddenly all LI's had the classes.

I still don't know what triggered this, but I added the following, which seems to do what I need!

```
$.get('menus/menutest.html',function(data) {
   $('#menutest').append( data );
   $( "ul#menutest li" ).addClass( "ui-screen-hidden" );
   $( "ul#menutest li" ).addClass( "ui-li-static" );
   $( "ul#menutest li" ).addClass( "ui-body-inherit" );   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to have your append logic include the classes that are resulting in your styling. Given the classes you mentioned above, and your initial append, it might look like:

```
$.get('menus/menutest.html',function(data) {
   $('#menutest').append('<li class="ui-screen-hidden ui-li-static ui-body-inherit">' + data + '</li>');
})
```